# Getting updated data from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have an app with a User table that was populated by an export from the Active Directory user list.  Every couple of weeks the users send me another spreadsheet with the latest AD user list, and I have to update our User table with my own magic involving manipulating Excel and matching up usernames to know whether to insert or update.

I think it's time to automate this whole task.  The easy way would be to have a scheduled task that polls AD every so often and updates all user information.  But that might be a bit of a waste, since 99% of the time nothing will have changed between polls.  One answer might be if there's a LastUpdated field anywhere in the AD user list, so I can know whether my information for any given user is up to date.  Is there?

If not, is there any way of subscribing to some kind of push notification from AD, so that I don't have to keep checking, but when a user is inserted, updated or deleted, my app will get notified?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way for push notification (LDAP change notification control) but it is restricted to monitoring a single object or the immediate children of a container. Besides, it may greatly affect performance of server.

Instead you may pick the pull mechanism: DirSync or USNChanged.
I am using DirSync in my project and it's working fine.

For details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677625(v=vs.85).aspx